# The first and second terms of an arithmetic and a geometric series are the same and are equal to 12

Tags: sequences-and-series

The first and second terms of an arithmetic and a geometric series are the same and are equal to 12. The sum of the first two terms of the arithmetic series is four times the first term of the geometric series. Find the first term in each series.

Comment: If both series start $12,12$ they are both always $12$ and the sentences after the first do not make sense.  Please review the question.  Then show what you have done.  Substituting in the general form for terms of the series and seeing where this leads is often a good start.  You hope to get a set of simultaneous equations.

Comment: @RossMillikan I think he means "the first term of an arithmetic series and the second term of a geometric series". However, if this is the case, the given information is not enough to determine an answer.

Comment: @Nilknarf:  that could be.  I would wait for OP to clarify.